# PowerShell history of commands

Tags: powershell

I use Bash and PowerShell interchangeably, and find it quite annoying when I can't do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on my PowerShell Console.

Is there a plugin/alternate command that can help me switch between Bash and PowerShell seamlessly?

#### Update (2018)

PowerShell now supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48672221/326543).

Comment: Related: For all PowerShell history of all time, see *[How can I see the command history across all PowerShell sessions in Windows Server 2016?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104043)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An alternate command is to type e.g `#ls` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> keep pressing tab to cycle through all command history that starts with `ls`.

In previous versions you could type `ls` then <kbd>F8</kbd> to match history. Keep pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> to cycle through multiple matches.

Note:`ls` is just a placeholder in this case. Replace it with any command you want.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this applicable to just the current session? it doesn't seem to work when I close PS console and reopen..

Comment: There are techniques for saving the history using Get-History | Export-CliXml $home\pshist.clixml and the PowerShell EngineExiting event.  You can then reload that history using Import-CliXml $home\pshst.clixml | Add-History.  That can get quite large over time though so you would probably want to limit the size of the history saved out.

Answer (score 9):

As of today PowerShell supports the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> shortcut.

Simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> when in the PowerShell console and start typing any part of a command you have run before.

---

**Alternatively:**

Start typing part of a command you have run before, and press or hit <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Keep pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> to cycle through similar commands.

Comment: Note that this does **not** work with PowerShell ISE, just with vanilla (boring) PowerShell.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at PSReadline: https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine

This module supports interactive history search in emacs mode and you can bind Ctrl+R to ReverseHistorySearch in Windows mode if you prefer.

The long term goal of PSReadline is to make it much easier to switch from bash to PowerShell w.r.t. command line editing while providing a PowerShell experience, e.g. tab completion.